# Get multiple records for the same row of master table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, case

Hi friends I struggling with following scenario in SQL table
I have Got Two tables and need a table from querying them.
table 1 is USER table (Master).

```
USERID   USERNAME   EMAILADD    
 113       name1     q@q.com
 114       name2     b@bcom
```

Following is the 2nd Lookup table

```
userid districtid schoolid schoolNAme radius
 113    12332       35831    Fort       1.0 
 113    2332        35832    Spring     1.0 
 114    2334        35831    Spring     1.0
```

and following is my requirement

```
userid   username    emailadd   schoolid
  113      name1       q@q.com    35831
  113      name1       q@q.com    35832
  114      name2       b@b.com    35831
```

I tried following query

```
SELECT userID , userNAME, emailadd, phone, 
    (SELECT schoolid from Lookup 
           where UserID IN(select distinct userid from users)) schoolid 
FROM Users
```

but its not working at all.I am new to SQL server can any one please suggest a better way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `join` to connect tables

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userNAME, u.emailadd, u.phone, l.schoolid
FROM Users u
inner join Lookup l on u.userid = l.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple JOIN,

```
SELECT
    Users.userid,username,emailadd,schoolid
FROM
    Users 
INNER JOIN Lookup ON Users.userid = Lookup .userid
```

Also you may even want to use  "WITH(NOLOCK)" if your only going to select, and if there will be a lot more records you need to iterate through

Comment: + i take so sodding long to reply haha, not sure why this is downvoted?

Comment: I downvoted it: Using `nolock` does not affect the number of records being returned.

Comment: ofc it doesnt? why would it?

Comment: OH "and there will be alot more records" sorry you miss read it because of how its stated ill change it, meant o say if theres alot of records then you "may" want to use it

Comment: changed it, hope that clarify s my meaning